# /usr/bin/env: node: Permission denied in Docker container using Symfony 6 "Encore" tool

Tags: node.js, docker, symfony, nvm

I'm running a docker container with PHP and node installed through nvm. A Symfony 6 app is mounted into it.

I'd like to user Symfony 6's "Encore" tool to compile my assets.

I connect to my container like this:

`sudo docker exec -ti 860cb4e01268 bash`

And then I move to the directory when my symfony app is mounted.

Typing `npm run build` returns the following message `/usr/bin/env: 'node': Permission denied`

Node is installed and $PATH seems correct, when I type `node`, I can enter the node console as expected. Same thing if I type `/usr/bin/env: node`.

Still from inside the container, a `whoami` returns "root", so I don't get how I could have a permission issue.

Finally, if I directly run `node node_modules/@symfony/webpack-encore/bin/encore.js prod`, it works and builds my asset as expected.

I don't get why a simple `npm run build` won't work?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], especially your image's Dockerfile?  I wouldn't normally expect you to run any sort of build command inside a `docker exec` debugging shell, since that will be lost as soon as the container exits; I'd expect to see some sort of `RUN npm build` command in the Dockerfile instead.  There are also a number of problems with version managers like `nvm` in Docker and installing Node another way (maybe in a multi-stage build) could work better.

Comment: I'm new to Docker so I may have done a messy set up. The idea here was to be able to minify my CSS / Js files while editing them without having to recreate the container each time. I did follow your advice and installed node like suggested here https://askubuntu.com/questions/720784/how-to-install-latest-node-inside-a-docker-container. It now works as intended, so I'll mark this question as solved.

Comment: There's not anything especially valuable in the container, it's just a wrapper around your main server process.  What's wrong with recreating it (essentially the same as restarting your server)?

Comment: I find it more convenient to be able to write my CSS and JS on the go, while having a "npm run watch" command which instantly rebuild and minify the files if the source has been edited than having to recreate the container. But I guess what I should do is to have a dedicated nodejs container which does just that.

Comment: Acutally, I just tried this last option and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing node through nvm, I installed it like suggested here https://askubuntu.com/questions/720784/how-to-install-latest-node-inside-a-docker-container. A `npm run build` now works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I finally updated my docker-compose.yml file like this:

```
  nodejs:
    image: node:16.16.0
    working_dir: /website
    command: npm run watch
    volumes:
      - /home/path-to-my-website-files-on-host-machine:/website
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
```

This way, each time I edit something in a js or css file, everything gets automatically rebuild and minified by Symfony Encore/Webpack